# Capistrano not deploying paperclip images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, capistrano

I have a Rails 4 app using the paperclip gem to store images at #{Rails.root}/public/system/... which works fine in development.

I have checked a handful of the development images into the above folder, but they aren't appearing on the Ubuntu 13.10 EC2 instance that I am deploying to. I am using Capistrano to deploy, and it seems to be creating all the symlinks fine:

`ls -l releases/20140402123457/public/system
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 28 Apr  2 12:35 releases/20140402123457/public/system -> /var/www/alpha/shared/system`

But the shared directory being linked to does not contain my images. How do I populate the /var/www/app/shared/public/system directory? I assumed Capistrano would do this for me, but it is empty.

I have searched many capistrano / paperclip threads for the answer, and I have tried all the capistrano deploy commands I can find in Capistrano -T. I believe I am using default locations for paperclip, and the paperclip documentation suggests the path I am using: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage

My Gemfile.lock shows the Gems I am using here: http://pastebin.com/iDv1Qm5K.

I've been scratching my head and am staring to wonder if I am going mad. Do I need to manually copy the development images into the shared/system directory? I have checked the images are in git and are extracted when cloning, so I am hoping I have covered the basics on daft mistakes that could be causing this. Any advice on how to investigate this further would be much appreciated.

Comment: this is not directly supported, and probably not what you want? unless you also "deploy" (copy) your development database to your production instance using capistrano.

Comment: Hi Marian, I am seeding the database with a seeds file, and it refers to the images I am using. It's only intended for the first few images in the application, such as default / missing images. And yup, Capistrano does the db seeding. All cap tasks look like they succeed, and this does work if I manually drop the images into the shared folder. However, I'd like a way to automate the image deploy so that I can do unattended cloud deploys. Thanks, Simon

Comment: you can always write your own cap task and hook into the deployment chain, see [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Getting-Started) or [here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/cold-start/)

Comment: thanks, I think you're right, a custom task looks like the way forward. I guess the way the shared directory is linked _to_ the checked out code shows that there is an expectation that checked out directory will be empty. I'll put the images somewhere else and copy them into the shared dir with a cap task. Thanks for the advice, it's much appreciated. I can stop banging my head against the wall now :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the tips from Marian Theisen, I have fixed this by moving the seed image files from the /app/public/system directory to /app/assets/seed_images/.

I then created a cap deploy task in config/deploy.rb to copy the images over to the shared directory:

`namespace :deploy do
  desc "Move seed images into place"
  task :move_seed_images_into_place, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{release_path}; cp -R app/assets/seed_images/* #{shared_path}/system"
  end
end`

And added `after("deploy:update_code", "deploy:move_seed_images_into_place")` to my config/deploy/staging.rb file.

In short, the answer is that I was doing the wrong thing by trying to share public/system between my dev machine and staging hosts. Instead, I have moved the seed images to a named location and I manually move them into place on my staging hosts.

This also has the benefit that I can trash the images I am using in development without trashing the install - I have a snapshot of the images I want saved in the app/assets/seed_images directory.